# Selecting rows with max value in a column

Tags: mysql, database, select, max

I am trying to select the rows in numTimesPurchasedTable which have max value on the column numTimesPurchased

```
SELECT item, title, MAX(numTimesPurchased) 
FROM (SELECT Purchase.item, Item.title, SUM(quantity) AS numTimesPurchased 
FROM Item INNER JOIN Purchase ON Item.id = Purchase.item 
GROUP BY item, title) AS numTimesPurchasedTable;
```

numTimesPurchasedTable looks something like this

```
item title numTimesPurchased
1    a     4
2    b     7
3    c     7
```

However, I am getting the error: "Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'numTimesPurchasedTable.item'"

Is there a way to do accomplish this in one query?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the single row with the greatest value, then use LIMIT:

```
SELECT Purchase.item, Item.title, SUM(quantity) AS numTimesPurchased 
FROM Item INNER JOIN Purchase ON Item.id = Purchase.item 
GROUP BY item, title
ORDER BY numTimesPurchased DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Is there a workaround for two rows have the same max value? I couldn't figure that part out

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? The solution to cases such as the one you describe is to use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) so you can get the row(s) with rank 1 instead of position 1.